# Keras LSTM harmonic prediction

Tags: python-3.x, keras, lstm

I'm playing with keras+TF. I have a model which is composed by a 
4 LSTM layers + 2 dense layers.

I have 3 features which are 3 sin sequences and a target which is the multiplication of the 3 sin sequences.

The LSTM layers are configured with 30 backlog time-steps.

I train the RNN with 80% of the features and than I request it to predict
the learned data (80% of the total data) I obtain a very good prediction.

Next I proceed with the last 20% of data splitting it in 10 sub-parts and 
looping in predict(part_x[0]), fit(part_y[0]), predict(part_x[1]), fit(part_y[1])...   But the quality of prediction dramatically drop down.

Is correct to expect that a predict(x[i])/fit(x[i],y[i]) loop should produce a decent outcome for every x[i+1] block?

Yet another question: is possible to train an RNN with 4 features and predict it with 3 features?  If yes, how can I "blind" the unavailable features on prediction phase?

TIA
Roberto C.